# Insert into DbContext Multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am getting the following exception when trying to add new entities to `DbContext` from some tasks, the code worked before adding tasks to the matter.

> $exception    {"The context cannot be used while the model is being
>   created."}    System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

I've done some research and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750115/the-context-cannot-be-used-while-the-model-is-being-created), and it contains some usefull information to my problem:

> Another reason for this error can be that while you create the context
>   the first time and therefore cause the model to be created you create
>   another context on a separate thread. You will have to wait for other
>   context instances to be created after the model creation has
>   completed.

So I guess the question is what is the proper way to wait for the context?

Here its my code in case I'm guessing wrong about my problem:

```
using(SampleEntities context = new SampleEntities())
{
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; //I tried this in case it was the problem
    Task[] TaskArray = new Task[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < TaskArray.Length; i++)
        TaskArray[i] = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                SampleEntity Result = null;
                while(this._Data.TryDequeue(out Result)) //where Data is a ConcurrentQueue<SampleEntity> with the entities to insert
                {
                    if(!context.SampleEntity.Any(/*Comparisons between properties to check if the entities values are already inserted*/)
                        context.Add(Result);
                }
            }
    Task.WaitAll(TaskArray);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The exception is thrown at the line `if(!context.SampleEntity.Any(...`

**EDIT:**

I have a large amount of registers previously enqueued in `_Data` and I was trying to make the mass insert faster if possible.

Comment: You said *I am getting the following exception when trying to add new entities* but forgot to add the exception details

Comment: `DbContext` isn't thread-safe.

Comment: Also, parallelism in EF will give you nothing, because EF creates separate insert for each new value, so you'll lack performance.

Comment: This look like the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your solution wont work, and you'll probably not get the desired effect (which looks like a bulk insert). Perhaps you should explain what *you want to do*, and not *how you need it done*.

Comment: I added a brief explanation.

Comment: You need to look into [`EntityDataReader`](https://github.com/matthewschrager/Repository/blob/master/Repository.EntityFramework/EntityDataReader.cs) and `SqlBulkCopy`

Answer (score 1):

One context and many threads - it is a bad practice. It is best to create the context for each thread. I could recommend to you reconsider your algorithm and reate the context for each thread.